# Sending of 8 bit or 16 bit data

Tags: serial, communication

I want to know if I send the 8 bit or 16 bit data how can I get separate value at the another end from one processor to another.
As example I am sending 42587 and I want only  4 to receive at another end not any other value. Same as for 2, 5, 8,7. I am using serial communication interface.
Using any thing like simple maths or any thing. Please help me.
I am using UART I mean that I am sending 42587 number but I want separated values from it 4 to be separate from that value like wise 2 & 5&8&7 also be separate

Comment: What you are asking seems unclear to me. Are those values sent as ASCII characters or byte values? Is the serial interface a UART or some other serial interface such as SPI, I2C etc? And what do you mean by "I want only 4 to receive at another end not any other value"? If you send 4, you should receive 4...

Comment: Are you in fact asking how to convert a hexadecimal (or binary) number to decimal?

Comment: Aren't you the programmer? Can't you parse the numbers from the uart any way you wish?

Comment: can u tell me how to parse the value 42587

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to send decimal 42587 (binary 1010011001011011) as ASCII string "42587" then

Convert the number to binary coded decimal (BCD). So 42587 becomes 0h00042587.

Send each byte of the BCD as it's ASCII character by adding 0h30. The transmitted string then becomes 0h30 0h30 0h30 0h34 0h32 0h35 0h38 0h37.

```
BCD    0000-0000 0000-0100 0010-0101 1000-0111
BCD       0    0    0    4    2    5    8    7
ASCII  0h30 0h30 0h30 0h34 0h32 0h35 0h38 0h37
```

See http://ascii.cl/.

Comment: So then I will get the values separately at another end for 4  and others value

Comment: Of course. That will be character 0h34.

Comment: i got what u explained me but one thing i am not understanding that how can i apply this in my program

Comment: How could I possibly answer that? You have given no information about your hardware or software. In any case, I think that is a new question.